# Spread image over axis space in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to create a data graph and want to add an image/sketch on top of that plot. However, with the code below, the image width is limited to the x-size of the graph below, or with other words: Although I don't have an y-axis on the image, I'm wasting the space there.

How can I make the image area cover the full width?

My Code until now:

```py
fig, ((ax,ax0)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=False, sharey=False, 
                    figsize=[5,4],gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[1,4],'hspace':0.05})

ax0.set_xlabel('X AXIS LABEL')
ax0.set_ylabel(r'Y AXIS LABEL')

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.text(.5,.5,"IMAGE",ha='center',va='center')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: What I have until now]

Comment: Do you want to resize the image, or just fit the plot to the image?

Comment: It's a sketch, also made with matplotlib. So I don't mind about the scaling to first order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the gridspec yourself and let the top subplot span two rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,4])
gs = GridSpec(2,2, height_ratios=[1,4], width_ratios=[0,1])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:])
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])

ax0.set_xlabel('X AXIS LABEL')
ax0.set_ylabel(r'Y AXIS LABEL')

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.text(.5,.5,"IMAGE",ha='center',va='center')

fig.tight_layout(h_pad=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution! The problem is now, if I add the hspace argument to GridSpec, the image is reduced by the area of the y axis label. Any idea why?

Btw I'm still using matplotlib 2.2.2...

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use `hspace` when calling `tight_layout` afterwards. So what exactly is the aim then?

Comment: I want to reduce the whitespace between the two subplots, aka `tight_layout` is not tight enoug for me. Thanks to your keywords, I found `gs.tight_layout(fig,h_pad=0.2)` which does exactly the what I want!

Answer (score 1):

`imshow` can do it!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests

r = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Rodger_Young.jpg', stream=True)

with open("young.jpg", "wb") as file:
  file.write(r.raw.read())


image = plt.imread("young.jpg")
plt.imshow(image)
```

Gives:
[image: Rodger Young]

All the familiar methods of `plt` should still be accessible to you.

```
r = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Rodger_Young.jpg', stream=True)

with open("young.jpg", "wb") as file:
  file.write(r.raw.read())


image = plt.imread("young.jpg")

plt.suptitle("Rodger Young")
plt.axis("off")

plt.imshow(image)
```

Gives:
[image: Cleanly rendered Rodger Young, with title]